# Lightweight View Models For WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I understand MVVM's usefulness in the context of a large team developing a shrink-wrapped application over a long period of time.  But in the context of an internal LOB application, MVVM seems overkill and I'm having trouble swallowing the overhead of debugging declaritive databindings, jumping from layer to layer to layer, and extracting VM's that are barely more than the Model with a command or two.  Even accepting that overhead, still leaves me with the holes in MVVM like dialogs.  A few things I've considered is:

- Binding directly to the Model and do old-school event handlers for form interaction
- Binding a user control or window to itself, effectively using the code behind as the VM.
- Include a property in my VM to reference the related view.
- Make ViewModel's subclasses of a View.

The above items and their combinations address some problems but not all.  I do realize that I might sacrifice testability.  What other technical (not conceptual like SOC) issues will I run into using one or more of these practices?

Comment: While there are benefits like separation of concerns and code re-use that you get when using MVVM, keep in mind that MVVM is primarily about being able to test your business logic separate from the actual view. If unit testing of your application is important to the project, then MVVM is a good choice and probably worth the associated 'overhead'.

Comment: I disagree.  View Models should not have business logic, they contain the logic associated to the ui.  Our business logic/model layer IS unit tested.  But the costs associated with publishing in a typical shrink wrapped or commercial product barely exist in an internal LOB application, so we beleive there is little point to unit test the UI, which puts us in this place of also wondering the usefullness of MVVM in it's purest form.

Comment: I disagree, ViewModels should never contain UI logic. Anything related to the UI such as setting focus or running animations should be done in the code behind. The ViewModels should contain Business Logic such as Loading/Saving data, and they should control application flow such as changing what ViewModel is the currently active screen, or returning error messages. Your ViewModels ARE your application, while the Views are just a pretty UI that allows users to interact with the ViewModels easily.

Comment: I could see your point if the context wasn't LOB applications.  But in this as well as most LOB apps, I have a middle teir in the form of WCF.  This teir along with the Models do all the heavy lifting in terms of data validation, saving, and generating error messages.  So in terms of the VM, a save command on a VM is a single line call to WCF.  What is left, I consider UI information defined in business terms.  For example a prop like "IsBusy" or "Selected" denotes a state of business processing, but it would be a tough sell to call this a concern of the business.

Answer (score 2):

I always use MVVM when coding in WPF or Silverlight, even for small single-page apps. It makes it much easier to test and maintain in the long run, and I find it faster to create apps with it than without it

I don't mind taking some shortcuts in smaller apps, such as binding to the Model instead of exposing the Model's properties in the ViewModel, or defining my View in a DataTemplate instead of a UserControl, or using Window's Dialogs in my ViewModels, but I would never consider doing a WPF or Silverlight app without MVVM.

If you want, I have an example of a very simple app done with MVVM [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)

Comment: The struggle I'm having with all samples including those like this:

Comment: The struggle I'm having with all samples including those like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-implement-MVVM-71a65441 all are extremely simple examples.  Things like dialogs, wait cursors, etc, are things being hammered out by the community, but even where I find an acceptible solution, I have trouble adding 30 lines of code to my framework for something that would be one line of code in a winforms environment.

Answer (score 0):

Code re-usability comes to mind. Properly written VM's could be re-used behind Silverlight or WP7 implementations down the road.